# Adding value to Hashing in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have an hash which has data something like :

```
details = [{
  :project_name=>"ABC", :project_id=>12345, :total_count=>1, 
  :stories=>[#<TrackerApi::Resources::Story id=987654>]
}, {
  :project_name=>"XYZ", :project_id=>54321, :total_count=>1, 
  :stories=>[#<TrackerApi::Resources::Story id=123456>]
}]
```

I want to insert another array with data such as :

```
sorter_Version = [["Abc ", "30 August 2017"], ["Not Accepted", "30 August 2017"]]
```

in details hash , but somehow not able to do it. can someone please help me out .Thanks in advance.

Output should be like :

```
details = [{
      :project_name=>"ABC", :project_id=>12345, :total_count=>1, 
      :stories=>[#<TrackerApi::Resources::Story id=987654>],
      :sorter_version=>["Abc ","30 August 2017"]
    }, {
      :project_name=>"XYZ", :project_id=>54321, :total_count=>1, 
      :stories=>[#<TrackerApi::Resources::Story id=123456>],
      :sorter_version=>["Not Accepted ","30 August 2017"]
    }]
```

Comment: _"somehow not able to do it"_ – can you show your approach, what have you tried? Was there an error or an unexpected result?

Comment: @Stefan i tried details.push(sorter_version), and then it got appended at last. but that is not what i wanted.

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve]. [so] is not a "write-my-code-for-me-service"! If you are looking for *that*, hire a programmer.

Comment: "somehow not able to do it" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also provide a [mcve].

Comment: @JörgWMittag Next me i will make sure that i mention everything.... it was my first query so not aware of this thing ... and i know "Stack Overflow is not a "write-my-code-for-me-service"! " , needed a little helpto get the concept.Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `each_with_index`:

```
details.each_with_index { |d, i| d[:sorter_version] = sorter_Version[i] }
#=> [{:project_name=>"ABC", :project_id=>12345, :total_count=>1, 
#     :stories=>["#<TrackerApi::Resources::Story id=987654>"], 
#     :sorter_version=>["Abc ", "30 August 2017"]}, 
#    {:project_name=>"XYZ", :project_id=>54321, :total_count=>1, 
#     :stories=>["#<TrackerApi::Resources::Story id=123456>"], 
#     :sorter_version=>["Not Accepted", "30 August 2017"]}]
```

Immutable version:

```
details.map.with_index { |d, i| d.merge(sorter_version: sorter_Version[i]) }
```